# Emit to a particular client who started the request socket.io. Get socketid in router

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have the following **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// var responseHandlerRouter = require('./routes/responseHandlerRouter.js');

routes = require('./routes');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

app.use('/', routes(io));
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (io) {

    // all of this router's configurations

    router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
        io.emit('notification', 'news');
        res.end('well finally I am here');
    });

    return router;

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/login');

        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do a get on the URL, it emits the string 'news' to the browser, but its sent to all the clients.If i open up multiple browsers, its sent to all of them. How do I emit to a particular client? or how is it possible to get the socketid inside the router. Is it possible using the io object?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to rethink your design here. Typically you'd get your reference to a particular client from the connect event

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('Hello World');
}
```

In your case you're passing in a reference to the entire io object. You may need to setup a way to handle the connection event and create a map (array in JS) between socket handles and client IDs. You can then reference the socket handle from the map by some sort of identifier coming from the `req` parameter inside your router.

Personally I've never used a router with socket.io and would recommend using namespaces or rooms.